# Arcpy Calculate Geometry (coordinates)?

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator

Does anyone know if it is possible to Calculate Geometry with Arcpy? I need to replicate the command > Right click field and Calculate Geometry except with Arcpy as I need to integrate this into my model.

Looking for some examples on how to do this.`arcpy.CalculateField_Management("sample.shp", "LAT", "...X, Y", etc..`
using ArcGIS 'Basic'

Comment: Have you looked at the scripting example for calculating centroids in the Calculate Field tool? Do you want to be able to add values in a different coordinate system than the data's?

Comment: no current coordinate system is fine, I just want to invoke this action with arcpy to automate a process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Toolbox Scripting tool called *Add Geometry Attributes* that you can use to create and populate a new attribute with areas and lengths.

Comment: But I don't want area or lengths, I want coordinates only,

Comment: That's available too: POINT_X_Y_Z_M, and CENTROID/CENTROID_INSIDE if you are working with polygons. Passing a geographic coordinate system (spatialReference object) to the Coordinate_System property should return Latitude and Longitude for the fields. Using @GBG suggestion saves you from creating fields too.

Comment: How do I do this? Does anyone have a code example so I can alter the format to field calc (using coordinate Calc geometry)?

Comment: do I use arcpy.CalculateField_management(shape.shp, field, "!arcpy.point(!X!, !Y!)" ?? I can't get this to work, so any code examples would be appreciated.

Comment: arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management("sample.shp","POINT_X_Y_Z_M") and it will automatically append the fileds Point_x and Point_y. Assuming that sample.shp is a point feature class. If you would like it in Latitude and Longitude, first create a spatial reference object: sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326) (this one is for WGS84) and then use the same code as above with the Coordinate_System property: arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management("sample.shp","POINT_X_Y_Z_M",Coordinate_System=sr)